# Replacing repeating strings in R

Tags: r, string

I have a column that looks like

```
v1 <- c("A","A","A", "B","B","A","A")
```

and I would like to remove each repetitive letter until the next different string so the structure would be

```
 c("A", "","","B", "", "A","")
```

Any tips on how to do this in R?

Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103175/discussion-between-ananda-mahto-and-akrun).

Answer (score -1):

We can either use run-length-type function (`rleid`) from `dat.table` to create a grouping index based on the repeating value, apply `duplicated` to get a logical vector (TRUE for duplicate elements), subset the vector and convert those duplicates to `''`

```
library(data.table)
v1[duplicated(rleid(v1))] <- ''
v1
#[1] "A" ""  ""  "B" ""  "A" ""
```

---

Or we use `base R` methods to compare adjacent elements by removing the first and last element (`v1[-1]`, `v1[-length(v1)]`).  The output will be of length 1 less than the original vector.  So concatenate with `FALSE` to make the length equal, subset the vector and change those elements to `''`.

```
v1[c(FALSE, v1[-1]== v1[-length(v1)])] <- ''
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c("A","A","A", "B","B","A","A")
```